# 422 unprocessable entity en fastapi

Tags: python, machine-learning, fastapi, devops

Tengo un modelo de regresión logística que quiero meter adentro de una api con fastapi, pero me genera el error "422 unprocessable entity". Estoy enviando a la api un archivo json y devuelvo un archivo json con la predicción.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel
import joblib

app = FastAPI()
 
class Input(BaseModel):
    # Define the input structure
    input_data: dict 

@app.get('/')
def main():
  return 'Hello World!'

@app.post('/predict')
def predict(input_data: Input):
    # Load the model
    model = joblib.load('model/model_diabetes.pkl')
    # Make predictions
    predictions = model.predict(input_data.input_data)
    # Return the predictions as a JSON object
  return JSONResponse(content=Response, filename='predict.json'
```